# HTML not linking with CSS in Hugo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, colors, hugo

I'm messing around with some pre-fabricated theme in Hugo using a bit of bootstrap codes, and I just want to change the color of all links at displaying, at hovering, etc. I've searched a lot and it says that I have to put a:link{...}, a:visited{...}, a:hover{...}, a:active{...} in this order into my css. I've also tried to put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="kitab.css">
```

in my html after someone who said it. None of the variants work, the link are blueish, and I just want to know how to make the connection between html and css.
My html portion (I'll provide it all if this is not a really simple problem) lists some clickable titles, which correspond to pages in the site:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled ml-1 mb-0 border-top border-warning pt-2">
    {{ range first 4 .Pages }}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">
        <p class="mb-1">
          {{ .Title }}
        </p>
      </a>  
    </li>
    {{ end }}
  </ul>
```

, and this is my whole CSS:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-width: 250px;
}

nav {
  height: 40px;
}
main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.side-bar {
  width: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
}
footer {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-left: 35px;
}
.nav-menu {
 /* color: #007bff !important; */
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.nav-menu:hover {
 /* color: #0056b3 !important; */
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-menu-disabled {
 /* color: #4e4f50 !important; */
  font-size: 1.5em;
}


/* the link colors here */

a:link {
  color: green;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: pink;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}








.book-cover {
  color: white;
/*  background-color: #24242499; */
}
.bookTitle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 5%;
}
.bookAuthor {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  right: 5%;
}
.show {
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
.hanging {
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-indent: -15px;
}

/*
ul.nav li a, ul.nav li a:visited {
    color: orange !important;
}

ul.nav li a:hover, ul.nav li a:active {
    color: orange !important;
}

ul.nav li.active a {
    color: orange !important;
}

*/

#copiedMessage {
  position: fixed;
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 224px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 112px);
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please do not post templating but instead post the rendered HTML

Answer (score 0):

I fully understand what happened now, and I think Hugo beginners should see this, because I wasn't warned of this in any tutorial.

In Hugo you can import a theme. What I did is move the CSS file from the static of the theme to the static outside the theme (my project). So, it was actually a problem of linking CSS with HTML in Hugo (that's why I changed the title of the main post). If you have a portion of code in your theme and some portion of code outside that theme, that may cause you problems in Hugo.

The solution was to move the files that I'm interested from the theme into my project (outside the theme), destroy the rest of the theme altogether, and remove the theme variable from config.toml. Another solution would have been to put everything (besides the files from the content folder) into the theme.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.